# kubernetes ingress empty address

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Firstly I am not using minicube , I had installed docker desktop.
I have install nginx ingress controller by following the documentation https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#generic-deployment
(without using helm)

**command : kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx**

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-hplk7        0/1     Completed          0                 3d4h
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-xcg56         0/1     Completed          0                 3d4h
ingress-nginx-controller-6bf7bc7f94-hnzqq   1/1     Running            5 (13m ago)       32h
nginx-ingress-controller-86c9965b78-mq7jf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   190 (3m46s ago)   3d5h
```

**MY DEPLOYMENT AND SERVICE YAML**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: #pods which deployment has to manage
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: zura123490/auth
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector: # it will look for pod with name of auth (e.g metadata:labels:app:auth)
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**Ingress Service File**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

**COMMAND kubectl get ingress**

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   hello-world.info             80      4h55m
ingress-service   <none>   ticketing.dev                80      35s
ingress-srv       <none>   posts.com                    80      32h
```

** kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc  **

```
C:\Users\anike>kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx                        LoadBalancer   10.107.56.91     localhost     80:31035/TCP,443:30306/TCP   3d19h
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.97.237.85     <pending>     80:32752/TCP,443:30029/TCP   3d19h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.105.128.130   <none>        443/TCP                      3d19h
```

I have done changes in host file  **127.0.0.1 ticketing.dev**  (As I m following tutorials (about microservices) I m just following the instructor )

**------PROBLEM---------**

ticketing.dev/api/users/currentuser

should lead me to the page which should ( as shown in tutorial)

**RESPONSE TO THE URL**

Response should be this "Response from auth: Hi there!!"

```
app.get("/api/users/currentuser", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Response from auth: Hi there!!");
});
```

But I m getting this response

```
This site can’t be reached 
ticketing.dev unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

But it is not showing anything , its not even opening up , so I tried to look into this problem,
and check my running ingress  using command kubectl get ingress, and I found that address column
is emptied pictures is shown in the starting . I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: You seem to have included a bunch of links to image files in place of the YAML artifacts and other source code required to demonstrate the problem.  Can you [edit] the question to replace these links with the actual source code and error messages; directly in the question and not behind links, as code-formatted plain text and not images?

Comment: @DavidMaze sir I have replace images with code , now can you please check it

Comment: The ingress controller is in CrashLoopBackOff state; do its logs say anything interesting?

Comment: @DavidMaze it is not in Crashloopbackoff now.... it only sometimes got into crash loop , because of lack CPU power (only in some cases)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the output of the command "kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc" maybe it will help a little